# What is the Roasterie's city of fountains blend?

Tags: flavor, roasting

I eat roasted coffee beans on occasion, and usually all taste about the same. But I have noticed that beans from the [Roasterie](https://www.theroasterie.com/)'s City of Fountains blend have a rather burnt flavor. I turns out the only place that they have been found is at Costco; even the cafés don't carry it. Does anybody have any experience with this? Are the beans just burnt leftovers?

Answer (score 2):

Beans that are sold by giant retailers aren't known for being great.  Most companies moving such a significant amount of coffee (and mostly cheaply) are mainly looking for a supplier who can provide a large volume and quality secondarily.  Dark roasting such beans effectively hides the origin flavors (or lack thereof) and provides a certain level of uniformity (you will consistently get the roast tastes).  It's unlikely the beans are "burnt leftovers" since that kind of sorting or sale to another company after over roast accidents would only add to the cost and complexity of getting the product to market.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear. The Roastery is a small roaster that is local to Kansas City. But is your point that if they are shipping to many areas it will need to have that darker roast? It's labeled as a medium roast, does that have anything to do with it?

Answer (score 1):

Those beans are only available in the Kansas City area Costco's so they are not selling them all over the US.  Quality is as good as any other coffee bean the Roasterie sells (which is very good).